# Multi property lambda groupby does not return correct result

Tags: vb.net, lambda, group-by

Trying to group a list of records with lambda but does not work with multiple property

I hate stake over flow, here is a bunch of text that is not need because stack over flow say I need more text because there is too much code and there stupid validation system keeps say my code is incorrectly formatted and I have spent to much time trying to get this to post

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim list As New List(Of MyObject)
        list.Add(New MyObject() With {.Batch = "", .Expiry = New Date(2001, 1, 1), .Serial = "S1"})
        list.Add(New MyObject() With {.Batch = "", .Expiry = New Date(2001, 1, 1), .Serial = "S5"})
        list.Add(New MyObject() With {.Batch = "", .Expiry = New Date(2001, 1, 2), .Serial = "S2"})
        list.Add(New MyObject() With {.Batch = "", .Expiry = New Date(2001, 1, 3), .Serial = "S3"})
        list.Add(New MyObject() With {.Batch = "", .Expiry = New Date(2001, 1, 4), .Serial = "S4"})

        Dim distinct As List(Of MyObject) = list.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Batch = x.Batch.ToUpper().Trim(), .Expiry = x.Expiry.Date}, Function(x) x).Select(Function(x) New MyObject() With {.Batch = x.Key.Batch, .Expiry = x.Key.Expiry, .Serial = ""}).ToList()
    End Sub

    Public Class MyObject
        Property Batch As String
        Property Expiry As Date
        Property Serial As String
    End Class
End Module


'Expected Results:
'item 0: Batch = "", Expiry = 2001/1/01, Serial = ""
'item 1: Batch = "", Expiry = 2001/1/02, Serial = ""
'item 2: Batch = "", Expiry = 2001/1/03, Serial = ""
'item 3: Batch = "", Expiry = 2001/1/04, Serial = ""

'Actual Results:
'item 0: Batch = "", Expiry = 2001/1/01, Serial = ""
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to remove that paragraph, or you may have other better place to ask the question, thanks.

Comment: Tried removing the comment said that there was to much code and yet someone managed to answer the question all the same. Simple put stack over flows rules are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss a keyword `Key` in your group by

Your code:

```
list.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Batch = x.Batch.ToUpper().Trim(), .Expiry = x.Expiry.Date}, Function(x) x)
```

But it should be

```
list.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Batch = x.Batch.ToUpper().Trim(), Key .Expiry = x.Expiry.Date}, Function(x) x)
```

[Fiddler](http://rextester.com/SOVBF85762)

Comment: Thanks you that is perfect :)

Comment: @user1626874 please mark this as answer if it can solve your problem